# How to update jar file within war

Tags: java, maven, jar, war

I have a big war file contains lots of jars inside lib directory. Uploading this war at testing environment takes a lot of time. For testing purpose I needed several time to make changes inside dependent jars sources of other modules , then rebuild the war file and upload to test functionality. It again take lots of time.

I know to update jar/war file we can use **jar uf** command

When I tried to update jar inside war , then war  corrupted. 
Can any body let me know how can I update that particular class file inside jar of war file. Or update jar itself inside war file.
Also let me know if there is any alternative for my problem.

Comment: have you tried to extract the `.war` file using a archive software and replace the required `.jar`

Comment: Then how would I again repackage it create war file at testing environment

Comment: suppose with a software like 7zip when the `.war` file is modified it asks whether to repackage.

Comment: will try it and update, thanks

Comment: Using 7zip to modify a war's contents got the war corrupted for me. I recommend you to use `jar uf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open a war using 7zip and copy paste the new jar inside it and save the war.

Comment: I have to upload it at linux cluster, looks 7zip is only for windows based systems

Answer (score -1):

Let's think simple :)

1 Backup your war file.

2 Rename war into zip. (mv abc.war abc.zip)

3 Unzip abc.zip into a temporary folder (unzip abc.zip)

4 Replace your jar files

5 Zip files again. (
This is tricky, cd into temporary folder you created in 3rd step
zip czf /pathToDestination/abc.zip *

6 Rename the created file to .war

Comment: Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile when I do this steps